# Execute batch file through php

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I had a script that worked in Win 7 and Win 10 upgraded from Win 7, but after i did a clean install of Win 10 the same script stopped working for some reason.

PHP

```
    print_r(shell_exec('test.bat '.$link));
```

The batch(test.bat)

```
    start launcher.exe "%*"
    exit
```

*Note The path in both cases are correct, thats not the issue.(full path edited out here for simplicity)

It does run the batch file but it does not launch the launcher.exe file for some reason like it did on my old win install.  I do remember doing something to fix it so it worked on the old install, but can't remember what i did or if it's different in Win 10(clean).

Comment: Are the php script, batch file and launcher all located in the same directory? If not was the folder they were located in your PATH variable?

Comment: Squashman: Let me put it this way, if i change the batch file to copy a file instead, it does so. So path is not an issue. Also just running the batch from windows myself also makes it work so that eliminates all path issues.

Comment: Does it help to add `""` as the first argument of `start`?  `start "" launcher.exe "%*"`

Comment: Update: Curiously the script does what's intended when i run it from Xampp shell commandline `php test.php`

Comment: Update2: Issue is solved. Do not run server as an administrator, simple as that.